# Scatter function getting "ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y"

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am getting this error when setting the s value to an array position, if i leave it like s = 50, it works but do not know the reason:

```
def Overlay_Points(Image_In_Path, Image_Out_Path, Points_Array):
plt.clf()
im = plt.imread(Image_In_Path)
implot = plt.imshow(im)


for c in range(len(Points_Array)):
  if Points_Array[c][3] == 1:
    plt.scatter(Points_Array[c][0], Points_Array[c][1], 'g', Points_Array[c][2])
  else:
    plt.scatter(Points_Array[c][0], Points_Array[c][1], 'r', Points_Array[c][2])

  plt.savefig(Image_Out_Path)
plt.close()
return 1



Overlay_Points('Anillo.jpg', 'ejemplo.jpg', [[1000, 1000, 50, 1], [2000, 2000, 100, 0]])
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per scatter plot documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), the third entry is size and fourth is color. You appear to have written it in reverse. You can either reverse the order or specifically say `s=` and `c=`. Once I made that change, the code appeared to run fine...

Change the code like this...

```
        if Points_Array[c][3] == 1:
            plt.scatter(Points_Array[c][0], Points_Array[c][1], c='g', s=Points_Array[c][2])
        else:
            plt.scatter(Points_Array[c][0], Points_Array[c][1], c='r', s=Points_Array[c][2])
```

Comment: You are right, the position of the parameters was wrong. It is working now.

Thanks!